# Looking to recover the product attribute for a cart item

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to recover an array of attributes for products in the Woocomerce cart

This is the code I have written (I am a beginner)

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
global $product;
$my_product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
echo "ID is {$my_product_id} \n";
$my_attribute = WC()->product->attribute->get_name($value); 
}
```

However I get "Call to a member function *get_name()* on null"

I think I am getting the items *product_id* 's OK (using *echo* to view). BUT I am not sure how to use the function get_name() or indeed any of the methods in the object *WC_Product_Attribute*

I guess I am working outside the loop?

I am writing this code into a WordPress 'page' in order to develop it, using a plugin which wraps the code in tags - [insert_php] & [/insert_php]

Help much appreciated, but I need to understand what I am doing wrong conceptually.

Correct code from LoicTheAztec produces as the third element of array (the attribute I want to retrieve)

```
'pa_1_scale' => 
object(WC_Product_Attribute)[1410]
  protected 'data' => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => int 1
      'name' => string 'pa_1_scale' (length=10)
      'options' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      'position' => int 2
      'visible' => boolean true
      'variation' => boolean false
```

Comment: Is this block of code you wrote wrapped in a function?

Comment: No, the code is wrapped in the tags [insert_php] & [/insert_php]

Comment: To get the protected data, you can use `get_data()` method from WC_Data class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code for that is:

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    // HERE the WC_Product object
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id']; 

    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
    foreach($attributes as $taxonomy => $value){
        // The WP_Term object
        $term_obj = get_term_by( 'slug', $value, $taxonomy );
        $term_name = $term_obj->name;
    }
}
```

Tested and works

Comment: That works, but how do I dig deeper into the array to retrieve the ID - see appended output above

Comment: @Cheerychops Just updated … With `$term_obj ` there is everything… You can make a `print_r($term_obj);` to see all the available data.

Comment: Hi definitely  making progress but get error "Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in C:\wamp\www\wizstaginglocal\wp-includes\formatting.php on line 1514"

Comment: Sorry I added my slug name, error gone. However not returning any data, I am wondering whether the data is protected.

Comment: Correct will do, thanks! ps I think the last line needs a ";"